# retrieve single value from the database every hour and send to another page

Tags: php, mysql

I need to write a php script which runs every hour,

so, in my database i have 7 tables which represents the days of week like sunday, monday, tuesday etc, and all the tables have 25 columns which represents 24hours like 1am, 2am, 3am etc  and a timestamp column.

so, now i have to write a php script which uses cron to run this script every hour.

Comment: What single value you want? Can we have the MySQL Dump please?

Comment: This seems kind of odd.  If you just want to find out the current day and hour, why not just do it in code?

Comment: I'm with Mike on this one, it's a bit unclear what you're trying to do. It almost looks like you have this complex database system set up just to get the current date ?

Comment: @Mike Brant , how do i find out the current day and hour in the code? I mean what changes should i do?

Comment: @user1586243 See my answer below related to `date()` function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the php `date()` function to get current date information in various format without needing to use DB.

Here is the link to the PHP manual.

http://php.net/manual/en/function.date.php

Some examples straight from linked PHP manual page.

```
<?php
// set the default timezone to use. Available since PHP 5.1
date_default_timezone_set('UTC');


// Prints something like: Monday
echo date("l");

// Prints something like: Monday 8th of August 2005 03:12:46 PM
echo date('l jS \of F Y h:i:s A');

// Prints: July 1, 2000 is on a Saturday
echo "July 1, 2000 is on a " . date("l", mktime(0, 0, 0, 7, 1, 2000));

/* use the constants in the format parameter */
// prints something like: Mon, 15 Aug 2005 15:12:46 UTC
echo date(DATE_RFC822);

// prints something like: 2000-07-01T00:00:00+00:00
echo date(DATE_ATOM, mktime(0, 0, 0, 7, 1, 2000));
?>
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, the date function worked!

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you change your DB design to just a single table?

CREATE TABLE `days` (
  `days_id` int(10) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `days_day` tinyint(1) NOT NULL,
  `days_hour` tinyint(2) NOT NULL,
  `days_value` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`days_id`),
  UNIQUE KEY `days_day` (`days_day`,`days_hour`)
);

Then just query:

$sql = 'SELECT `days_value` from `days` where `days_day` = ' . date('W') . ' and `days_hour` = ' . date('H') . ' limit 1';

Makes getting things out much much easier.

Comment: Please indent code with four spaces for proper formatting.

Comment: the values to the database comes from the front end, so the values keep changing all the time , if i create a single table how will i retrieve the values everytime